# mongoTemplate.upsert not saving _class

Tags: spring, mongodb

I've noticed that when I use `mongoTemplate.save` I have an extra field on document stating the class:

```
{
   _id
   name
   description
   _class: "Pet"
}
```

I've noticed that ehdn a document is created using `mongoTemplate.upsert` the `_class' field is missing.
I know that's the way mongo is performing the "magic" casting.
This can make some inconsistencies in the DB.
Is there a reason or solution for this?

Comment: @Alex.T Not sure i understand what you mean, and yeah, `i only got the class name because im using @TypeAlias("Pet")

Comment: yeah my bad, I'm reading while having lunch, I got the question in the end. You can ignore that comment

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? @user2101699

Answer (score 0):

The mongoTemplate.upsert method actually does not make use of the MongoMappingConverter Class that is responsible for adding the "_class" attribute to the document that is going to be persisted. There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/2910

As a workaround you can inject MongoMappingConverter and call write. This method takes two parameters. First one is the entity, second one the target bson document. Simply initialize a new bson document then put this into mongoTemplate.upsert . In debug mode you will now see the "_class" attribute.

This attribute might seem not to be necessary but if you use repository methods with examples these will fail to work cause these methods select documents by attribute "_class".